# Match rows and columns of two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

For example:

I want to rearrange rows and columns in `df_1` such that they match rows and columns in `df_2`. I know that column names and row names are the same in both matrices, and both matrices have the same shape.

```
>>> df_1
      col1  col2  col3  col4
row1     0     1     2     3
row2     4     5     6     7
row3     8     9    10    11
>>> df_2
      col3  col1  col2  col4
row2    24    25    26    27
row3    28    29    30    31
row1    32    33    34    35
>>> df_1_new
      col3  col1  col2  col4  # rows and columns of df_1
row2     6     4     5     7  # are in the same order as in df_2
row3    10     8     9    11
row1     2     0     1     3
```

My code:

```
col_names_1 = np.array(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
col_names_2 = np.array(['col3', 'col1', 'col2', 'col4'])

row_names_1 = np.array(['row1', 'row2', 'row3'])
row_names_2 = np.array(['row2', 'row3', 'row1'])

data_1 = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
data_2 = np.arange(24,36).reshape(3,4)


df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_1, index=row_names_1, columns=col_names_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_2, index=row_names_2, columns=col_names_2)
```

My_solution:

```
df_1_new = df_1[df_2.columns].T[df_2.index].T
```

I feel like talking the transpose twice is redundant, and that I am missing a simpler solution. Is there  a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will form the union of the indices

```
df1, df2 = df1.align(df2)
```

This will simply make df1 indicies like df2

```
df1 = df1.reindex_like(df2)
```